# a strange problem in shopify slideshow section

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Hope you guys doing well.

so i'm using Swiper js to create a slideshow section, the real problem is in theme editor, when i add the section and click on slide 2 for example my script not working, but when i save the changes it works fine.

did i miss something?

here is what i've wrote for changing slide when click on each slide

```
 {% if request.design_mode %}
        $(document)
        .on('shopify:section:load', MakeTheSlider )
        .on('shopify:section:unload', process_slick_event )
        .on('shopify:section:select', process_slick_event )
        .on('shopify:section:deselect', process_slick_event )
        .on('shopify:section:reorder', process_slick_event )
        .on('shopify:block:select', process_slick_event )
        .on('shopify:block:deselect', process_slick_event );
      {% endif %}
 
  function process_slick_event(evt){
        if(evt.detail.sectionId === '{{section.id}}'){
          var CurrentSlide = $("#slideshow-{{ section.id }}").find('#'+evt.target.id).data('index');
 
          $("#slideshow-{{ section.id }} #pagginat-{{ section.id }} :eq("+CurrentSlide+")").click();
        }
      }
```

i have another question.
why js code does not work when user add a section and it needs a save or refresh to works fine?
do we have any solution about that?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about. If you add external JS files. It will take some time to load. If an editor is open it looks like it's broken. Once you save it then it's fine. happened to me as well while using slick and owl-carousels.

Comment: hi you are right but imagine user wants to see the changes on slide 3 when click on slide nothing happens, even unable to see any changes, so it is not nice enough.and what about if a user is not an advanced user and is quite unfamiliar with shopify, so when add the section and nothing happens what would think?